# Some helping reading this method in Scala. Is this a block?

Tags: scala

I just need some verification about code that I'm writing. Mind helping?

```
private def placeOrder[Thing1: Type1, Thing2: Type2](
    message:          Message,
  ): Future[Order Or Reject] = logOnTimeout(
    {
      WaitFor[Order Or Reject](message) { (client, id) =>
        WaitFor {
          case o: Accepted if getOrderId(o) == id =>
            <do stuff>

          case r: Rejected if getRejectOrderId(r) == id => 
              <do other stuff>
        }
       ...
  )
```

I'm having trouble understanding this line:

```
WaitFor[Order Or Reject](message) { (client, id) =>
```

What is the stuff in brackets? IS that a block in Scala? Are we passing it anonymous function? I guess brackets are the same thing as parenthesis but multiline? Is that right?

Here is the method implementation and as I can see, it uses currying and the second argument is a function type:

```
def WaitFor[A](message: Message)(waitFor: (Person, Id) => WaitFor[A]): Future[A] = {...}
```

So I can see this `WaitFor` method returns a Future of type `Order Or Reject`? Is that right?

Also what is this: `Future[Order Or Reject]`? What is a future exactly in scala?

Comment: Square brackets indicates type information. The `Or` operator is a type-level operator that says either `Order` or `Reject` values can be produced by the enclosed method.

Comment: Wanna give a more fleshed answer? How do futures work?

Comment: A `Future` makes a promise to eventually return a value or an error. Depending on the context, the future may be run in a separate thread, or started later. Fundamentally, `placeOrder` will eventually produce a result. Meanwhile, read up on Scala `Future`s as this is a fairly hefty topic. Lots of answers on stackoverflow, too.

Comment: Want to give a more fleshed answer and I'll credit it?